# Sorting mySql results using LIKE '%variable%'

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a search form on my website that allows users to search for employees in a company. I'm using the input to search a table in a mySql DB. My SELECT state is here:

```
SELECT title, uid FROM table_data 
WHERE title LIKE '%$search_name%' AND blog_id = 6 
ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 50
```

Currently, a search for 'Jon' would result in some like:

```
Angela Jones
Dejonas Lucero
Ernesto Jon
Jon White
Rick Jonston
```

Is there a way to have it sort in this order?

```
search_name%
%search_name
%search_name%

Jon White
Ernesto Jon
Angela Jones
Dejonas Lucero
Rick Jonston
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can sort by relevance? If so you may want to look into a full text index and match against.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about full text index. I just spent a little while reading about it. While the answer below works for now, this definitely sounds like a better solution for me long term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way to do it, although I feel it's not very elegant:

```
SELECT title, uid FROM table_data 
WHERE title LIKE '%$search_name%' AND blog_id = 6 
ORDER BY IF( title LIKE '$search_name%',0,
             IF( title LIKE '%$search_name', 1, 2 ) )
```

LIMIT 50

It assigns each title a '0' if it matches 'search_name%', 1 if it matches '%search_name', and 2 otherwise (which is '%search_name%' by virtue of the WHERE clause).

Then it sorts by it (ascending).

You could also do it with a `CASE WHEN..THEN..END` statement:

```
SELECT title, uid FROM table_data 
WHERE title LIKE '%$search_name%' AND blog_id = 6 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN title LIKE '$search_name%' THEN 0
              WHEN title LIKE '%$search_name' THEN 1
              ELSE 2
         END
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to issue three separate queries and concatenate the result sets.  You could do it in one query as follows:

```
SELECT '1' as q, title, ...  WHERE title LIKE '$search_name%' ...
UNION
SELECT '2' as q, title, ...  WHERE title LIKE '%$search_name' ...
UNION
SELECT '3' as q, title, ...  WHERE title LIKE '%$search_name%' ...
ORDER BY 1,2
```